# Firebase Authentication React with Node backdend

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, firebase, authentication

I have an application that I am developing. It uses Mongo+JS backend to store users and other stuff which use geographic points in map.

I am doing that for a college traine lab, and they have teach us to use Firebase in Authentication in the frontend, not in the backend, so Users are created on Firebase, and Mongo just receives it Firebase UID to associate the other data to a user.

I am finding it very strange, should it not be better to be done in Backend, so it can provide to both web and phone apps? Isn't a bad practice, to frontend implements a service that the backend will kind of consume to validate its own data?

And should not be better I just keep using Mongo for store users and make auth?
What you guys think about that? Does you guys have some experience about it?

Firebase it's better than a API context backend for auth? Should I do it on backend, and make frontend just send the data to create and validate users?

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems to me that the more layers that there are in your application, not only are there more chances that an error can spring up but also more work for you to do.

I've used the approach that you're currently taking before and at first, I used Firebase Auth to sign in the user on the front end and then the Admin SDK for CRUD operations on the backend, along with duplicating some data to MongoDB.

It eventually became difficult to have to manage two services and it really is redundant to copy data from Firebase and duplicate into MongoDB.

I see two ways of fixing this:

1. Use only Firebase and not MongoDB to authenticate users (sign in / sign out) in the front end and perform CRUD operations on the Auth level in the backend and use either Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore as your main DB with the Admin SDK

The only real benefits to the above is that you can make use of the Firebase Auth third-party sign-in provider features (Sign in with Google, Facebook, Github) and that you can stick with the authentication process that you're familiar with.

2. If you'd like to keep MongoDB, then all you need to do is take the same capabilities that Firebase provides in the Auth service and create a new collection with those users and manage the state of the user account with normal CRUD operations. Of course, some manual work is required since you'll need to integrate third-party authentication providers yourself.

It seems better to choose one option or perhaps try out the current approach and see if it is manageable.